# Tridion OData service documentation

Tags: tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Is there any documentation on Tridion's OData service?  I have a link to the Tridion documentation ([here](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011SP1/index.aspx)) but I don't see anything for the OData service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in the installation procedure then you can find it [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_DC046ED58691440E92ED1A8672851427) for Java or [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_3E3A2FB1B4E34C20934B5A841C2E0930) for .NET. For more details about what you can do with this OData WebService you can take a look [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_DFBA3FF3977045F892ABB4FCF8DA38B1).

Note that you need to login for all three links (login information is in your initial link).

Hope this helps.